# PyObject_Str segfault on ctypes passed dictionary

Tags: python, c, api, python-2.7

So, I have this C code:

```
#include "Python.h"

void check(PyObject* pdict)
{
   printf("About to instantiate PyString!\n");
   PyObject* mdstr = PyObject_Str(pdict);
   printf("Python dict: %s\n", PyString_AsString(mdstr));
}
```

Which I am able to compile and link into a shared library named 'libTmp.so'

Then I use this ctypes code fragment to invoke the 'check' function:

```
from ctypes import cdll, py_object, CFUNCTYPE, POINTER
SO = cdll.LoadLibrary("libTmp.so")
prototype = CFUNCTYPE(py_object, py_object)
check = prototype(('check',SO))
```

But when I try to invoke the 'check' function I get a segfault from the line:

```
PyObject* mdstr = PyObject_Str(pdict);
```

check({'one':1}) for example will segfault...

I suspect it is either a misunderstanding of the proper use case on my part or perhaps a unicode issue?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Turns out this has been asked and answered elsewhere on StackOverflow by [Mr. Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen%20...)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218281/267157