# How to access the data members in a python class object that was passed to C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-extensions

Say I have a python class object:

```
class A:
    pass

o = A() 
o.a=8 # or any data type such as numpy arrays
```

and I want to pass that python object to C++ extension:

```
import cpp_lib

cpp_lib.run(o)
```

From the C++ side, I want to access the member of the python object:

```
static
PyObject *run(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject * python_object;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &python_object))
    {   
        std::cerr<<"Error parsing python_object from python to cpp extension"<<std::endl;
        return Py_None;
    }   

    // std::cout<<python_object.a<<endl;

    return Py_None;
}
```

The python object member could be a numpy array.

Note: Cython is not an option.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213072/passing-python-objects-as-arguments-to-c-c-function-using-ctypes

Comment: I just found it out myself a minute ago:)